# Can't apply() custom functions to a WindowedStream on Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm stuck trying to coding custom logic for the Window's apply() method. Basically I want to reduce all elements from a Window, and then appending a timestamp to that value, so I created a WindowedStream from a DataStream, but when I try to define the functions for the apply() it fails at compile time.

This is the code:

```
class WindowReduceFunction extends ReduceFunction[(Int, String, Int)] {
  override def reduce(a: (Int, String, Int), b: (Int, String, Int)) : (Int, String, Int) = {
    (a._1, a._2, a._3 + b._3)
  }
}

class WindowTimestampAddFunction extends WindowFunction[(Int, String, Int), (Int, String, Int, Long), (Int, String), TimeWindow] {
  override def apply(key : (Int, String), window : Window, in: Iterable[(Int, String, Int)], out: Collector[(Int, String, Int, Long)]) {
    for(row <- in) {
      out.collect((row._1, row._2, row._3, window.maxTimestamp()))
    }
  }
}
```

The DataStream is of type [Int, String, Int] and the key is [Int, String]. The code without apply() runs and compile without errors, but is when I type:

```
myWindowedStream.apply(new WindowReduceFunction(), new WindowTimestampAddFunction())
```

When it fails and can't compile, giving the error:

```
[ERROR]   [R](preAggregator: ((Int, String, Int), (Int, String, Int)) => (Int, String, Int), windowFunction: (org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple, org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow, Iterable[(Int, String, Int)], org.apache.flink.util.Collector[R]) => Unit)(implicit evidence$6: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[R])org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream[R] <and>
[ERROR]   [R](preAggregator: org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.ReduceFunction[(Int, String, Int)], function: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.function.WindowFunction[(Int, String, Int),R,org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple,org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow])(implicit evidence$5: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[R])org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream[R]
[ERROR]  cannot be applied to (WindowReduceFunction, WindowTimestampAddFunction)
[ERROR]       .apply(new WindowReduceFunction(), new WindowTimestampAddFunction())
[ERROR]        ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using either an index position key, as in `keyBy(1)` or a field expression key as in `keyBy("field")`. This means that the key type of the `WindowedStream` is type `Tuple` (`org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple` to be specific).

If you change the third generic argument of your `WindowFunction` to `Tuple` from `(Int, String)` it should work. You can also change your `keyBy` call to use a lambda function, then you can get the correct specific key type in your `WindowedStream`. For example: `keyBy( in => (in._1, in._2)`.